# Derivative Of A Function Defined In Terms Of An Infimum

Tags: real-analysis

Let $A \subset \mathbb{R}^n$ be compact and let $\Phi: \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $\displaystyle \Phi(x) = \inf_{p \in A} ||p - x||_2^2$. I want to find the total derivative of $\Phi$, but I don't know what to do with this infimum. Is it possible to interchange the infimum and a partial derivative?

EDIT: Since $A$ is compact, I suppose it should be a minimum, not an infimum. I will add then, to my question, about what happens if $A$ is bounded but not closed and we have an infimum.

Comment: $\Phi$ is not differentiable everywhere. For example, if $A$ is a square (not including the interior), then $\Phi$ will not be differentiable on the diagonals of that square. The infimum/minimum and derivative are definitely NOT interchangable. To your edited question, you get the same $\Phi$ from $\overline A$ as from $A$ itself, so there is nothing gained from relaxing the compactness condition.

Comment: Thank you for your response! Yes, a square is a good example of what could go wrong. I'm going to post a new question asking if this could work if $A$ is a smooth, embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (since a square is not an example of this).

Comment: Here it is for reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3031295/derivative-of-infimum-embedded-submanifold-of-mathbbrn