# Derivative Of Infimum - Embedded Submanifold Of $\mathbb{R}^n$

Tags: multivariable-calculus, differential-geometry

This is a follow-up question to:

[Derivative Of A Function Defined In Terms Of An Infimum](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3030687/derivative-of-a-function-defined-in-terms-of-an-infimum?noredirect=1#comment6250113_3030687)

Let $A$ be a compact, (smooth) embedded submanifold of $\mathbb{R}^n$ and let $\Phi : \mathbb{R}^n \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $\displaystyle \Phi(x) = \inf_{p \in A} ||p - x||_2^2$. Does $\Phi$ have a total derivative everywhere? How does one go about finding the total derivative of $\Phi$? Is it possible to interchange the infimum and a partial derivative?

Comment: The reason my square counter-example in the other thread worked wasn't because it was not smooth. It worked because it wasn't convex. For any non-convex set, there will be points outside of it for which there are closest points in $A$ to it in more than one direction. $\Phi$ will not be differentiable at any such point.

Comment: And no, it is still NOT possible to exchange an infimum and partial derivative.

Comment: Ah, I see. Thank you.